# "Скажи мне что ты сказал, и я скажу кто ты" - правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, спп, ссп

Выступает ли в этом предложении союз *что* в роли подчинительного союза в СПП? Или же это ССП, где однородные сказуемые *скажи* и *сказал* относятся к местоимению *ты*? И вообще, если *что* не входит в состав неразложимых словосочетаний, то он обязательно является подчинительным союзом в СПП и отделяет придаточную часть от главной запятой?

P.s. Вопросы, должно быть, глупые, но в последнее время у меня какой-то нездоровый интерес к русскому языку проявляется. Надо бы за учебники сесть, поумерить пыл.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скажи мне, кто твой друг, и я скажу тебе, кто ты. ([Энциклопедический словарь крылатых слов и выражений)](http://bibliotekar.ru/encSlov/17/84.htm)

Скажи мне, что ты слушаешь, и я скажу, кто ты ([НАУКА И ЖИЗНЬ](https://www.nkj.ru/news/26706/))

Аналогично:

**Скажи мне, что ты сказал, и я скажу, кто ты.**

[Скажи мне, что ты сказал], и [я скажу, кто ты] - ССП.
[Скажи мне], (что ты сказал) - СПП, союзное слово *что*.
[я скажу], (кто ты) - СПП, союзное слово *кто* (не уверен).

Comment: М_Г: [Скажи мне], что [ты сказал] - СПП, **союз** _что_. === ???

Comment: М_Г: [я скажу], [кто ты] - **БСП**. === ???

Comment: Объясните мне, пожалуйста. "(Ты) скажи мне" - здесь подразумевается подлежащее "ты" и сказуемое "скажи", верно? То есть это определенно-личное предложение. Скажи мне что? "что ты сказал", здесь "ты" - подлежащее, а "сказал" - сказуемое? Или здесь "скажи" и "сказал" однородные сказуемые, которые относятся к первому "подразумеваемому" "ты", и запятая перед "что" не нужна?

Comment: Просто укажите мне на ошибку в моих рассуждениях, чтобы я понял.

Comment: @slava1947, Не уверен, что придаточное может состоять из одного слова (ты). Помогите.

Comment: @Уроборос. Однородные сказуемые относятся к одному подлежашему (Я говорил, говорю и буду говорить), у вас не этот случай, а СПП (скажи мне (что?)....).  "Ты сказал" - простое предложение (ты - подлежащее, сказал - сказуемое )